# Mobile Safari IOS8 Javascript Not Fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following javascript attached to my form submission event:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
if ($(this).valid()) {
    // On submit disable its submit button
    $('button[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').html('<i class="icon-spinner icon-spin"></i>');
}});
```

Every time user submits the form, the button is disabled and a spinner is shown inside the button replacing the text

It works perfectly fine on every pc browser, works fine on mobile safari in every version of IOS except the new IOS8.

The event is not fired during submission and after the form  submission, javascript is somehow disabled/crashed, I couldn't toggle my menu bar, side bar and everything that requires javascript.

**Update:**

If i change my disable my button without adding a spinner icon, it works fine too

```
$('form').submit(function () {
if ($(this).valid()) {
    // On submit disable its submit button
    $('button[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}});
```

Comment: Were you able to see any errors in console?

Comment: @mohamedrias If you mean debug console, I think IOS8 removed it, on pc there are no errors, I think there isn't any errors, everything works fine if i remove the above javascript, but i still don't think its my javascripts problem